# Descend of a linear map to a linear map with respect to the quotient by an annihilator of source and target modules

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a commutative ring. Let $M, N$ be $A$-modules and let $I\subset A$ be an ideal contained in the annihilators of $M$ and $N$, respectively. That is, $I\subset\mathrm{Ann}(M)\cap\mathrm{Ann}(N)$. Assume further that $f:M\to N$ is a $A$-linear map.

Both modules $M$ and $N$ have a canonical $A/I$-module structure given by
$\bar{a}\cdot x=ax$ for every $\bar a\in A/I$, any representative $a\in\bar a$ and every $x\in M, N$. Does the $A$-linear map $f$ descend to a $A/I$-linear map via the rule

$$f(\bar a\cdot x)=f(ax)=af(x)=\bar a\cdot f(x)?$$

To me the above fact is evident but on the other hand it cannot be found in any textbook.

Answer (score 1):

The observation is correct. My opinion  regarding the unavailability of this as a theorem is perhaps because it can be regarded as a particular case of the following:

If $M$ and $N$ are $A$-modules, $B$ an $A$-algebra, then any $A$-module map $f:M\to N$ induces a $B$-module map $f\otimes 1: M\otimes B\to N\otimes B$ such that  $f(m\otimes b)=f(n)\otimes b$ for all $m\in M,n\in N,b\in B$.

In the present case, we can take $B=A/I$. Then $M\otimes (A/I)\cong M/IM\cong M$ as $A/I$-modules and a similar thing for $N$. Then $f\otimes 1$ as an $A/I$-module map from $M$ to $N$ will look like the the map that is described in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your response! You assume that $I$ is in the annihilator of $M$ and $N$ as in the question, right? Otherwise $M/IM\cong M$ would not make sense. Also, in the first line of the second paragraph, I assume that you meant  "...$B$ an $A$-algebra...", not "... $B$ and $A$-algebra...".  Can you correct these typos, pls.

Comment: yes, indeed. I will correct the typo.